# WebStorm cannot find usages of a exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a js file name business_video.js containing some functions. At the end I export them:

```
  module.exports = {
        checkShare,
        checkDownloadFile,
        uploadVideo,
        quickTransferVideo,
        searchVideoInshared,
        renameVideo,
        deleteVideo,
        addTags,
        deleteTag,
        downloadFileToFromHDFSToServer,
        doesFileExistInServer,
        videoSquare,
        getVideoInfoByIdsArray
    }
```

I want to find a function name `getVideoInfoByIdsArray`'s usage in the whole project, including those who use `const  abc = require('../business_video')` then `abc.getVideoInfoByIdsArray()`.

However I when I press F7 on 
`function getVideoInfoByIdsArray(){...}` it show the only usage is in the `module.exports={...}`. How can I find the usages in the whole project?

Comment: `module.exports = {
        checkShare: checkShare }` it should be like this

Answer (score 0):

You can search the file usage. Just right-click on the file on project files and select Find Usages.
WebStorm can find usages of exported module properties, but require(file) call is not treated as module usage.

Answer (score -3):

Make a global find, with defaul key map is *ctrl + shift + F*, and filter by file mask *js*, uncheck *case* and/or *regex*, and instead project select directory and set the root of project. In the search box paste the function name. If no results, means that not used!

Answer (score -3):

Use [export before declaration](https://javascript.info/import-export#export-before-declarations), and then "find usages" will find usages on other modules as well.

Comment: Seems it is supposed to work: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37211/Find-usages-doesnt-work-with-node.js-require but it's broken for me too.

Comment: Yeah, it's an open bug. Go vote for it!
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55383/Find-usages-doesnt-work-on-module-exported-with-module.exports